# Construction -치 못하다

Tags: grammar, verb

What exactly does 경탄을 금치 못하다 mean? I heard it several times in the northern propaganda documentaries and also it can be found in newspaper articles.

I guess it's something like "be unable to hide the joy". But why is it written as -치 못하다, not -지 못하다? And what does the verb 금다 mean, which I can not find in vocabularies?

Comment: ‘금(禁)하다’ “to suppress (one's emotions)”→ ‘금하지’ → ‘금ㅎ지’ (ㅏ contraction) → ‘금치’

Comment: Can we use -치 못하다 instead of -하지 못하다 everywhere?

Comment: Some get “-치” and some other get “-지” depending on whether the consonant before the “ㅎ” is voiced or not. Let me check out the grammar details.

Comment: Right, when it's unvoiced one, the “하” is elided, otherwise only the “ㅏ” is elided, the “ㅎ” gets merged up and aspirate the following consonant.

Comment: (Per [Hangul orthography, Chapter ⅳ, §5 (“Contraction”), Clause 40](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000072).)

Comment: related questions: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/625/etymology-of-%EA%B4%9C%EC%B0%AE%EB%8B%A4/627#627, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/634/can-i-use-%EC%B0%AE%EB%8B%A4-to-express-%EC%A7%80-%EC%95%8A%EB%8B%A4?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/10/negative-form-of-verbs-%ED%95%98%EC%A7%80-%EC%95%8A%EB%8B%A4-versus-%EC%B9%98-%EC%95%8A%EB%8B%A4?rq=1

Comment: there was another question about 원하지 않다 -> 원치 않다 but I can't find it now. If someone can find it please link it here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

금하다

1) prohibit

도박을 금해야 한다 We should prohibit gambling.

술을 완전히 금하고 있다 I have wholly given up drinking.

2) contain emotion

그 소식을 들었을때, 기쁨을 금할 수 없었다.

When I heard the news, I
could not contain a joy = I could not hide a joy on my face = I was
glad largely.

@ 금할 수 없었다 = 금치 못했다.

As Kohctahtnh Bah said, 금치 is a short form of 금하지. In my
thought, almost does not have a short form. For instance, **전하지**
못하다 (can not send). Further, as like 금치, there is another
example : 면하다 = I am free to a fixed duty.

A는 B를 상대로, 고전을 **면치** 못했다. A had a difficulty
 game.

Comment: So, can I (or is it necessary to) replace "-하지 + negation" to "치 + negation" everywhere?

Comment: Yes. "치 + negation" can be replaced by "하지+negation".